# Promise is not immediately returned for function

Tags: javascript, promise

I was trying to come up with a simple example to show how promises get around a blocking call, but this example isn't working the way I expect

```js
function blockForLoopPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0 ; i < 10000000000 ; i++) {
      
    }
    resolve("done")
  })
}

blockForLoopPromise().then(() => console.log("DONE!"))
console.log("END")
```

In this example, "END" is not called until the long for loop is completed. Shouldn't it be called immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be called immediately?

No. The function you pass to the Promise constructor is called synchronously.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters):

> A function to be executed by the constructor, during the process of constructing the new Promise object.

You can also see in the [specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-promise-executor) that the function is called immediately by the constructor (step 9).

Comment: I'm looking at the MDN docs and it says the executor function is called asynchronously: "Typically, it works like this: The operation within executor is asynchronous and provides a callback".  Still tryin to grok this

Comment: That sentence means that you typically call an async function *inside* the executor not that the executor is itself executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can update to the following to get the behaviour you're looking for. `setImmediate` is used in node to execute the function on the next iteration of the event loop

```js
function blockForLoopPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      for (let i = 0 ; i < 10000000000 ; i++) {
      
      }
      resolve("done")
    });
  });
}

blockForLoopPromise().then(() => console.log("DONE!")); 
console.log("END");
```